# sencha touch 2 id of view returning undefined

Tags: view, reference, controller, sencha-touch-2

I have declared a view as shown below:

```js
Ext.define('App.view.About', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
id: 'about',
xtype: 'aboutpanel', // used as reference from Main.js
config: {
            title: 'About',
            iconCls: 'icon-file',
            scrollable: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            items: {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'About'
            },
            html: 'This page will contain basic information.'
        }
  });
```

I have also declared a controller as shown below:

```js
Ext.define('App.controller.About', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

  config : {
    refs    : {
     about : '#about'
    }
  },

  init : function () {
    var me = this;
    me.getAbout().setHtml('Hello'); // just for testing
  }             
});
```

However in the Developer Tools of Chrome am getting an error "Cannot call method 'setHtml' of undefined". Therefore as I understand it, the controller is not getting the view by id. Am using Sencha Touch 2.2.1.

Any help please? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have access to the refs in the `init()` function of the controller.  To get similar functionality, you could do your code as an `initialize` listener on the `about` panel:

```js
Ext.define('App.controller.About', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config : {
        refs    : {
            about : '#about'
        },
        control: {
            about: {
                initialize: 'initAbout'
            }

        }
    },

    initAbout: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.getAbout().setHtml('Hello'); // works now!
    }             
});
```

As a side note, it is redundant to give your components an `id` in in the definition.  You should reserve `id` for when you're instantiating components (and you should probably use `itemId` instead of `id` in that case anyway).

Comment: yes it works now thanks. however when I remove id and add itemId in the config stanza, it does not work.

Comment: what is the correct code in the case of itemId? Also, on another note, once I remove the items stanza in the config of the view, no title appears. However the same code in the Main.js file (without the items stanza) results in a title with a different background...

Comment: I would also like to remark that I have another controller for a view that extends Ext.carousel.Carousel and I have no problem accessing refs from the init function without the control stanza... why is that pls?